# How to select multiple files with keyboard only in windows explorer

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

I know that we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left Click</kbd> to add a file to the selection in windows explorer. It is also possible to use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Arrow</kbd> to extend the selction to adjacent files.

**How can I select files that are not adjacent** though - without using the mouse?

I noticed that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Arrow</kbd> to move some kind of cursor onto a file without actually selecting it, but then how can I select the file I want selected once that cursor is on it?

<sub>Bonus Points if you also know how to jump to a filename and add this to the selection, but that would be a different question</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the question and answer! I'm also curious about how to do the task you've provided in the bonus point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to select or unselect the file that's currently under the cursor.
You can move with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Arrow</kbd>.